# Metal Dies for Cloth or Leather

Tags: cutting

I want to create some stamps or dies that kind of look like cookie cutters. I intend on cutting mostly layers of cloth, felt, and maybe a single layer of leather.

Does any one know of a good process to make these dies?

Comment: Right now this is pretty broad, and I can't tell if you're asking for a tutorial (which would be off-topic) or just a starting point for the process terminology (which might be on-topic, but I don't know enough about making dies). Can you focus this a little more to be specific about what problem you're trying to solve, what you've researched so far, and how the A&C community can help you out?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are talking about [steel rule dies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(manufacturing)#Steel-rule_die).

These use a flexible or semi-flexible strip of steel sharpened along one edge. This is embedded in a backing (sometimess fibre/particle board) usually sitting in a thin profile-cut slot which supports the steel cutting edge.

You can buy the prepared steel stock and make the dies yourself and there are also manufacturers who will make custom dies to your specification and they are relatively inexpnsive, at least by the standard of dies in general.

They are quite well suited to cutting resonably soft materials like paper, leather, and textiles. They work best when used with some sort of press.

I have made these myself in the past with some success when used with an arbour press. I cut the profile out of MDF with a fine coping saw and used thin shim stock to make the blades. This isn't quite as hard as the proper die stock but will just about work.

Comment: You may be able to harden the steel yourself (depending on the carbon content, and unlikely for stainless).  You should be able to put a bit of an edge on it with a sharping stone/diamond file for an easier cut.